# javascript - remove inline event handlers / attributes of a node

Tags: javascript, html

Given an HTML node from the dom,
I need to remove all inline event handlers / attributes such as: onclick, onmouseover, onmousedown etc.

I know that:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").attributes
```

returns all the attributes, and I can eliminate some attriubtes, but then there is also attributes like: id, class, name etc.

How do I seperate the two types of attributes?

Completely different approches for solving the problem are also an option.

EDIT: I'm trying to remove only inline events,
and I also need to "save" them elsewhere before deletion, so cloning for complete disposal is not an option

Comment: Are you trying to remove inline events only?

Comment: I was about to suggest jQuery but itsgoingdown has a JS solution.

Comment: I can use jQuery (although i would prefer not to because performance is important here), but I will if it's the only option

Comment: When you are "saving" them, how did you want them saved and to where? And it's safe to assume each element has an id?

Comment: Do you want to remove the event attributes from the DOM? or just desactivate for a monent the event callback calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you get all `element attributes`, make an *array* of em, check in for loop if any `attribute` starts with `on`. 
Then make an `object` with `name/value` of that `inline event handler`, `push` it into `array`, and at the end remove it from the node:

```
var el = document.getElementById("button1");
var listOfEvents=[];  
var attributes = [].slice.call(el.attributes);  

for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
    var att= attributes[i].name; 

   if(att.indexOf("on")===0){

     var eventHandlers={};
     eventHandlers.attribute=attributes[i].name;
     eventHandlers.value=attributes[i].value;
     listOfEvents.push(eventHandlers);
     el.attributes.removeNamedItem(att);             
   }     
}
```

Check the **below** snippet

```js
var el = document.getElementById("button1");

var listOfEvents = [];
var attributes = [].slice.call(el.attributes);

for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
  var att = attributes[i].name;

  if (att.indexOf("on") === 0) {
    console.log(att);
    var eventHandlers = {};
    eventHandlers.attribute = attributes[i].name;
    eventHandlers.value = attributes[i].value;
    listOfEvents.push(eventHandlers);
    el.attributes.removeNamedItem(att);

  }


}


console.log(listOfEvents);


/* logs   [[object Object] {
  attribute: "onmousedown",
 value: "mouseDown();"
}, [object Object] {
  attribute: "onmouseup",
  value: "mouseUp();"
}, [object Object] {
  attribute: "onclick",
  value: "doSomething(this);"
}] */
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="button1" type="button" onmousedown="mouseDown();" onmouseup="mouseUp();" onclick="doSomething(this);" value="Click Me" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, only that I have to "save" them before deletion in a spereate data structure. See my edit.

Comment: Edited answer, check it out `(inspect that button)`

Comment: 1) [Don't use `.nodeName`/`.nodeValue` on an `Attr`, use `.name` and `.value` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr#Deprecated_properties_and_methods), 2) Curiously there don't appear other non-event attributes, starting with `on`, although I'd still use a hardcoded list.

Comment: Also, I think using filter/map is simpler, even if you can't use the arrow-functions and replace them with regular ones: `Array.filter(el.attributes, (attr) => attr.name.indexOf("on")===0).map((attr) => ({name: attr.name, val: attr.value}))`

Answer (score 1):

Filter all attributes whose name starts with 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can name all the handlers you want to remove/check then this will work for you (it is basically searching for the attributes you give it and removes/saves them - added bonus, you can also remove some other attributes you want the same way, just add them to the list):

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9zgkar64/1/)

**Btw, IDK wtf am i suppose to post as "obligatory code" when linking fiddleJS... just check the link I extracted the javascript here but you are missing html**

```
var dataStorage = {};


function someFunction(num) {
  alert(num);
};


function removeInlineHandlers(elementID) {
  //Define all the attributes you want to remove;
  var removeableAttributes = ["onclick", "onhover", "onmouseout"];
  var attributes = document.getElementById(elementID).attributes;
  var addFlag = true;
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < removeableAttributes.length; j++) {
      if (attributes[i].name == removeableAttributes[j]) {
        // If this is the first attribute to be removed, add an object
        // to track the data of removeals.
        if (addFlag) {
          dataStorage[elementID] = {};
          addFlag = false;
        }

        dataStorage[elementID][attributes[i].name] = attributes[i].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById(elementID).removeAttribute(attributes[i].name);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function removeHandlersAndPrint() {
  removeInlineHandlers("btn1");
  removeInlineHandlers("btn2");
  removeInlineHandlers("btn3");
  removeInlineHandlers("btn4");
  console.log(dataStorage);
}
```